# Converse of Nakayama lemma

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with $1$ and $J(A)$ denotes the jacobson radical of $A.$ Let $I$ be an ideal of $A$ such that for every finitely generated $A$ module $M$ whenever $IM=M,$ $M=0.$ Then how do I show that $I \subset J(A).$

Give me some idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elementary version of rschwieb's answer : for $m$ a maximal ideal, what's $I(R/m)$ ? ($R/m$ is seen as an $R$-module)

Comment: By the condition $I(R/m) $ properly contained in $R/m.$ What next ?

Comment: But it's also a sub-$R$-module of $R/m$. Are there many of these ?

Answer (score 1):

In particular for simple modules, $IS=\{0\}$, so $I$ annihilates all simple modules. The Jacobson radical is the intersection of  annihilators of all simple modules, so $I$ is contained in it.